# Every directory shows up as modified using the Eclipse git plugin

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I've been struggling/ignoring this for some time.  I have a project ([ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/)) with a number of sub-projects: core, android, jdbc, tests, etc..  Everything is working ok with git and the repos except that all of the directories/folders in my `ormlite-tests` sub-project show up as modified from within the EGit plugin in eclipse.   Also, if there were files that were modified, they would not be marked as such inside of the same `ormlite-tests` project.  All my other sub-projects are working fine showing proper modification status.  If I do a commit or synchronize from EGit, no changes are found and refresh doesn't change this.

If you take a look at the following image you can see that the `BatchOperations.java` file is not modified but the `perf` directory is marked as modified.  This is true for all other directories under `ormlite-tests`.  `git status` from the command line shows no outstanding changes.   I've deleted and re-cloned this repo a *number* of times.  I've also recloned every all of the projects and as far as I can tell I'm doing the same thing with the `ormlite-jdbc` and the other repos which work fine.

[image]

I'm using EGit 2.3.1 with Eclipse 3.7.2.  Although I've only checked my code in from the web and one architecture (OSX), I thought it might be the CRLF stuff but changing the `core.autocrlf` setting did not help.  I've thumbed through some of the Egit bugs but not found anything that seems like a match.  My repos on github are: [core](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core), [jdbc](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc), [tests](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-tests), ...  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note that after you change the core.autocrlf setting, it won't take effect unless you check all the files out again. Easiest way to do this is to clone again, or delete all the workspace files and do a git reset --hard HEAD. I suggest double-checking this is not really the problem, since it's the first thing that comes to mind. After that, perhaps you can test with the command line git and jgit clients to compare what they show for status.

Comment: Thanks @djs.  As the post mentions, "git status from the command line shows no outstanding changes".  Also, I did try re-cloning after made the core.autocrlf setting.  I'd be more sure about trying that if all of the files looked to be modified when they really aren't.  This is about the directories.

Comment: I cloned the ormlite-tests repository and could not reproduce the problem (using EGit 3.0).

Comment: Wow thanks for trying @robinst.  I'll consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question but for posterity, this seems to have gone away with a new version of the Eclipse git plugin.  I am running right now EGit version 3.0.3 and I've not seen this problem for some time.